# cached getter/calculations pattern|boost class with dependency tracking

Tags: c++, design-patterns, boost, proxy, c++03

Is there are common pattern OR ready-to-use boost class for "cached calculation"/"cached getter"?

I mean something like this:

```
class Test{
public:
     Value getValue() const;
protected:
     Value calculateValue() const;//REALLY expensive operation.
     mutable bool valueIsDirty;
     mutable Value cachedValue;
}

Value Test::getValue() const{
     if (valueIsDirty){
         cachedValue = calculateValue();
         valueIsDirty = false;
     }
     return cachedValue;
}
```

I can use `std::pair<Value, bool>` and turn `getValue/calculateValue` into macro, but this doesn't really help if **value depends on other values** (stored in other classes) and those values can also be cached.

Is there a ready-to-use solution for this kind of "pattern"? At the moment I handle such cached values manually, but this isn't "pretty".

Restrictions:
c++03 standard. Boost is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up using:

```
template<typename T, typename Owner> class CachedMemberValue{
public:
    typedef T (Owner::*Callback)() const;
    T get(){
        if (dirty){
            cachedValue = (owner->*calculateCallback)();
            dirty = false;
        }
        return cachedValue;
    }
    const T& getRef(){
        if (dirty){
            cachedValue = (owner->*calculateCallback)();
            dirty = false;
        }
        return cachedValue;
    }
    void markDirty(){
        dirty = true;
    }
    CachedMemberValue(Owner* owner_, Callback calculateCallback_)
        :owner(owner_), calculateCallback(calculateCallback_), dirty(true){
    }
protected:
    Owner *owner;
    Callback calculateCallback;
    bool dirty;
    T cachedValue;
private:
    CachedMemberValue(const CachedMemberValue<T, Owner>&){
    }
    CachedMemberValue<T, Owner>& operator=(const CachedMemberValue<T, Owner>&){
        return *this;
    }
};
```

usage:

```
class MyClass{
    public:
        int getMin() const{
            return cachedMin.get();
                }
            void modifyValue() { /*... calculation/modification*/ cachedMin.markDirty();}
        MyClass(): cachedMin(this, &MyClass::noncachedGetMin){}
    private:
        int noncachedGetMin() const{ /*expensive operation here*/ ... }
        mutable CachedMemberValue<int, MyClass> cachedMin;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Proxy design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) can help with this.

A typical implementation will define a class `ValuePtr` that behaves just like an ordinary `Value*`, i.e. it has an overloaded `operator->` and `operator*`. But instead of directly accessing the underlying `Value` object, these operators also contain the logic of deciding to load or recompute the actual value. This extra level of indirection will encapsulate the proxy logic.

If you need to count refences to other objects, maybe `std::shared_ptr<Value>` is useful to use as the underyling data type inside `ValuePtr`.

See [this site](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/proxy/cpp/1) for a code example. [Boost.Flyweight](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/flyweight/doc/tutorial/index.html) might also help.